# copy - text functionality is broken in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, clipboard

Copy and paste some text between apps, broke the pasted app. When I restart the system, it is working as excepted, but after a time It starts to fail again.

Which application is responsible for copy-paste functionality? If Nautilus; it's version is 3.4.2. What kind of packages should I check? Maybe an installed package broke it.

EDIT: I use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V key combination for copy and paste respectively.

Comment: The applications manage the clipboard of the X server themselves, but they usually use a toolkit like GTK or Qt to do that, so I would look at the toolkit libraries and possibly the desktop manager. Do you have additional clipboard manager(s) running?

Comment: What is broken with copy - paste ? can you you describe the problem ?

Comment: lately I installed parcelitte, someone who experienced this problem suggested that as solution but did not worked for me.

Comment: e. g copy text from chrome to atom editor. or to another application like gedit etc. When I paste, Atom stops working,  gedit doesn't paste. E. g copy paste from Atom to Chrome; chrome stops working.

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you are activating copy and paste? It's unclear (at least to me) if you are utilizing key combos or the GUI.

Comment: Also found something [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946188). as @DavidFoerster suggested I added my search keywords `Unity` :)

Comment: In future please [edit] your question to add requested information as comments may get deleted for a number of reasons. In this case I've done it for you and it should show up after review.

Comment: You might find this an interesting work around: http://thecodecentral.com/2013/03/04/use-mouse-buttons-to-perform-copy-paste-in-linux-updated

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, are you copying and pasting between Atom and Chrome? A bug in 0.189.0 caused Chrome and Atom to hang if you were to copy and paste between them.

This has been fixed in release 0.190.0 (https://atom.io/releases) and it seems to be working fine now on my machine (albeit with fairly limited testing at this point).